# Multiple selection of three tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have three linked tables - **order_tab** which contains orders, **autosorder_tab** which connects two other and **auto_tab** which contains all cars in shop. 
  One order can contain any number of cars.

```
CREATE TABLE order_tab
(`id` int, `_phone` varchar(10), `_email` varchar(9), `_date` varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO order_tab
(`id`, `_phone`, `_email`, `_date`)
VALUES
(1, '111-111111', 'ok@ok.com', '2013-08-19')
;

CREATE TABLE auto_tab
(`id` int, `us_id` int, `str_1` varchar(3), `str_2` varchar(8))
;

INSERT INTO auto_tab
(`id`, `us_id`, `str_1`, `str_2`)
VALUES
(2, 0, 'BMW', '530i E60'),
(6, 0, 'BMW', '530i')
;

CREATE TABLE autosorder_tab
(`id` int, `au_id` int, `or_id` int, `hours` int, `price` decimal(19,2))
;

INSERT INTO autosorder_tab
(`id`, `au_id`, `or_id`, `hours`, `price`)
VALUES
(1, 2, 1, 3, 2700),
(2, 6, 1, 2, 3500)
```

**order_tab** *id* - is main. *or_id* from **autosorder_tab** is *id* from **order_tab**. *au_id* is id from **auto_tab**
How can I select all orders to all cars in each order?

Comment: So you want to return all the model names in an order as a single string, is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly just use `JOIN`

```sql
SELECT o.*, a.*
  FROM autosorder_tab ao JOIN order_tab o
    ON ao.or_id = o.id JOIN auto_tab a
    ON ao.au_id = a.id
 ORDER BY o.id, a.id
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0cd02/4)** demo

**UPDATE** If you want to group your information per order use `GROUP BY` and appropriate aggregate functions. For names of cars you want to use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```sql
SELECT o.id, o._date, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(a.str_1, ' ', a.str_2) 
          ORDER BY a.str_1, a.str_2
          SEPARATOR ',') autos,
       SUM(hours) hours,
       ...
  FROM autosorder_tab ao JOIN order_tab o
    ON ao.or_id = o.id JOIN auto_tab a
    ON ao.au_id = a.id
 GROUP BY o.id
```

To change a delimiter use `SEPARATOR` clause. Or use comma by default and then when iterating over the result set in your client code change it according to the presentation rules.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0cd02/14)** demo

Comment: This is also good, but do not need to duplicate order for each car. All cars should be in one order or I do not understand?

Comment: So far this is the best suitable option to me! Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible not to repeat the same car as second order?

Comment: @DevellMen: If you mean you want to suppress duplicate model names per order, you could use `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT...)` for that. If you mean something entirely different, please ask a new question.

Comment: @peterm: I mean count same cars as in "order 2". Example: Audi A6 (4 pcs.)

Answer (score 1):

Should be like below. Please try..

SELECTED `order_tab` all rows.

Then JOINED `autosorder_tab`, `auto_tab` and ORDERED by order id descending.

```
    SELECT * FROM order_tab 
INNER JOIN autosorder_tab ON order_tab.id = autosorder_tab.or_id 
INNER JOIN auto_tab ON auto_tab.id = autosorder_tab.au_id 
  ORDER BY order_tab.id DESC
```